# Sorting tagged photos from Instagram

Tags: feed, instagram

I am using istafeed.js to get the instagram feeds.

But It is sorting only few pictures. 
Here is the jsfiddle code: jsfiddle.net/fXDv5/1/

I want to sort all the pictures which are tagged by most number of likes. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine. I updated your fiddle to show the `Likes` count and it is sorting by **Most Number of Likes** `DESC`.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/fXDv5/4/